# Can you get the rainbow jetpack back?

Tags: ios, jetpack-joyride

So, when I installed jetpack joyride the rainbow jetpack was in the
game. I played the game so I could get it. But it suddenly was
not in the game. Now I can't get the achievement Hippie.
Please help.

Comment: It's not in the ingame store? It was in the game at release not a special time limited thing or anything so I'd be surprised if they removed it

Answer (score 0):

Because of a new feature, the JetPack store cycles through its listing. It might not be available today, but at a later date, it might be on sale, only to be switched out for a different JetPack afterwards.